# where to add certificates with rootless docker

Tags: docker, certificate, rootless

I have some private docker registries and I added their certificates in `/etc/docker/certs.d/[domain.name.com]/ca.crt` and it's working but my problem is that I have to use sudo with docker even if I am in the docker group and rebooting (multiple tries).

So I gave a try to rootless docker but now it seems that I can't connect anymore to my registries, I'm having this error: `Error response from daemon: Get https://domain.name.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

I added the same folders in certs.d under my `/home/$USER/.docker/certs.d/...` folder but it doesn't work neither.

Do you know if there is something to do with the certificates with rootless docker ?

Thank you so much for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution is to put the configuration to ~/.config/docker/certs.d/

Same post was answered on forums.docker.com: https://forums.docker.com/t/where-to-add-registries-certificates-with-rootless-docker/109800 which solved the problem for me.